# Tweet count just shot up

Tags: twitter

On our homepage we have a tweet button and counter:

http://www.scirra.com

This was around 600 until overnight it suddenly doubled to 1,200.  It's been continuing to rise at a normal rate since.

Has Twitter changed what counts as a Tweet for that counter?  I've noticed competitors counts have dropped significantly.  We don't buy tweets or followers, and I haven't found any spam tweets about us nor have we had any significant recent press.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it happened a few times already, that Twitter changed something on their counting-strategy.
I figured that out, when I checked my own count of Tweets. It was around 3000 and suddenly it was more then 5000 which was not possible during a day or so.

At first I thought that some app on my phone sent spam out or things like that, but there was nothing. And a week later, I had my ~3000 back.

When they do have those problems, they probably post it in their status blog: http://status.twitter.com/